# Is an SSL Certificate Authority Chain "Secret"

Tags: mariadb, security, ssl, certificate

We've recently signed up to use MariaDB's SkySQL package, however are new to the use of SSL Certificate Chains when connecting (having only really used SSH tunnels in the past).

We have the key which we downloaded via our web portal, however don't know whether this should be treated as secret like we would with a private key or whether this is public information.

Sorry, probably an easy question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to treat that certificate chain as secret. It is just like the public cert you can view when connecting to a website like stack overflow. The private certificate is being used server side.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected this to be the case but wasn't entirely sure.